# What to do if nothing returned in a Scala function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, return-type

I have a Scala function that has an explicit return type of `RDD`:

```
def myfunction(x:Int):RDD = {
  if (x==1) { 
    formRDD()
  } else {

  }
}
```

I don't know what to do with else, if I don't want to form an empty RDD.

Comment: What if you want isn't very relevant here. Imagine, if you wanted to return a String, while the function is declared to return RDD ... What then?

Answer (score 7):

If your function can either return an `RRD` or return "nothing", it should return `Option[RRD]`. In your branches you either return `Some(r)` or `None`.

[Read about `Option`](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html).

Answer (score 4):

Actually returning an empty RDD is a valid solution. I don't like returning Option when the enclosing type is a collection. The "empty" is perfectly defined in a collection so Option is sort of redundant.

```
// assuming you have sc in scope
def myfunction(x:Int): RDD[Int] = 
   if (x == 1) formRDD() else sc.emptyRDD[Int]
```

If you had to return a regular collection you would similarly do this:

```
def myfunction(x:Int): Seq[Int] = 
   if (x == 1) Seq(1,2,3) else Seq.empty[Int]
```

Writing `def myfunction(x:Int): Option[Seq[Int]] = ...` would be a bit wasteful.

Comment: If an empty collection cannot be a valid result for the first branch, returning an empty collection in the second branch is perfectly fine.

Comment: I see what you mean. In case you want to differentiate between an empty collection coming from `formRDD()` and an empty collection coming from`x != 1`. Yes, if that is something you care about, then returning an `Option[RDD[_]]` would make sense.

Comment: Hey@marios, Thanks, I think your answer is what I originally want. @9000 's explanation is also really helpful to me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

imho you should return an `Option`, so that you clearly indicate that this method may not have a `RDD` to return. In the method which invokes this one, you need to take care of the `None` case, probably doing `.getOrElse(RDD.empty)` .

While some may argue that this approach may be wasteful, it is a matter of separation of concerns. Of course, if you are doing a 10 line script, you don't need to worry about returning an `Option` and you may simply return the empty `RDD`

> Note: I'm note familiar with `RDD`, so I don't know how to generate an empty one